# Parse multi-part emails encoded in base64 utf8 using PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, base64, email-parsing

I have a multi-part message that I would like to decode (see below).

I'm able to use PHP's `base64_decode` function to decode normal emails, but it wont work for multi-part emails.

Is anyone aware of how to do this or know of any scripts available?

```
    --_000_FBA91459E616EF4B8C1CCF54B389A283030E5EMX105CL01corpemcc_
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

    SGVsbG8sIEkgY2Fu4oCZdCBzZWVtIHRvIGdldCB0aGUgbGluayB0byB3b3JrIGFmZmVjdGl2ZWx5
    IHRvIGVudGVyIGluIHRoZSBuYW1lcyBvZiBwZW9wbGUgdG8gc2VuZCB0aGUgc3VydmV5IHRvb+KA
    pml0IHdvbuKAmXQgbGV0IG1lIGVudGVyIHRoZSBuYW1lcy4gQmUgZ3JlYXQgaWYgeW91IGNvdWxk
    IGhlbHAgb3Igc2hvdWxkIEkganVzdCB3YWl0IGEgbGl0dGxlIHdoaWxlIHRvIGdhaW4gdGhlIGFj
    Y2Vzcz8NCg0KUmVnYXJkcw0... etc

    --_000_FBA91459E616EF4B8C1CCF54B389A283030E5EMX105CL01corpemcc_
    Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

    PGh0bWwgeG1sbnM6dj0idXJuOnNjaGVtYXMtbWljcm9zb2Z0LWNvbTp2bWwiIHhtbG5zOm89InVy
    bjpzY2hlbWFzLW1pY3Jvc29mdC1jb206b2ZmaWNlOm9mZmljZSIgeG1sbnM6dz0idXJuOnNjaGVt
    YXMtbWljcm9zb2Z0LWNvbTpvZmZpY2U6d29yZCIgeG1sbnM6bT0iaHR0cDovL3NjaGVtYXMubWlj
    cm9zb2Z0LmNvbS9vZmZpY2UvMjAwNC8xMi9vbW1sIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcv
    VFIvUkVDLWh0bWw0MCI+DQo8aGVhZD4NCjxtZXRhIGh... etc
--_000_FBA91459E616EF4B8C1CCF54B389A283030E5EMX105CL01corpemcc_--
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a PHP module called [mailparse](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mailparse.php) which can do the heavy lifting for you.

On top of that, check out [this wrapper](https://github.com/php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser) which will make it more easy to access the functions of the library.

We use the php module in our stack at [mailparser.io](http://mailparser.io) and it works very reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I found this library which does most of what I want (I made a few small customisations).

https://github.com/CaTzil/emailParser